# Probability that a card drawn is King on condition that the card is a Heart

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

> From a standard deck of 52 cards, what is the probability that a randomly drawn card is a King, on condition that the card drawn is a Heart?

I used the conditional probability formula and got:

Probability that the card is a King AND a Heart: $\frac{1}{52}$

Probability that the card is a Heart: $\frac{13}{52}$

So: $\frac{\frac{1}{52}}{\frac{13}{52}} = \frac{1}{13}$.

Is this correct?

Comment: yup. as an extra observation you can note that this is exactly the probability of drawing a king without any information on the color of the card drawn

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.  There are thirteen hearts, and only one of them is a king.

$$\Pr(K \mid \heartsuit) = \frac{\Pr(K \cap \heartsuit)}{\Pr(\heartsuit)} = \frac{^1\!/_{52}}{^{13}\!/_{52}}=\frac{1}{13}$$

Comment: +1 for correctness and for showing that "heart" can be a math symbol.  :)

Answer (score 1):

We want to work out $P(king|heart)$.

$P(heart)=1/4$

$P(king \& heart)=1/52$

Conditional probability formula: $P(A|B)=P(A \& B)/P(B)$.

So substituting into this formula we get:

$P(king | heart) = P(king \& heart) / P(heart) = (1/52)/(1/4) = 4/52 = 1/13$ as required.

So yes, you are correct.